# How to stop automatic boot entry creation

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi, boot-order

I previously used a Lenovo PC on which I have Ubuntu and Parrot installed in it. I then switched PC to HP EliteBook. To preserve state, I just switched the hard drive. When I tried booting, it didn't automatically show GRUB menu. After a day's work, I finally got it to work (I can't actually remember what I did exactly) following a tutorial using `efibootmgr`. Whenever I boot it, it shows:

```
System boot order not found initializing defaults
Creating boot entry "0007" with label "ubuntu" for file "EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi"
```

Then it shows the GRUB screen.

After a while of using my PC without any incidence I noticed that after showing the above, it had a new one:

```
Could not create variable, out of resource
```

Then it would eventually show GRUB screen.

Long story short, I did an inspection using `efibootmgr -v` and had the output:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0007, 0000,0001
Boot 0000* Notebook Hard Drive BBS(HD, 0x0)
Boot 0001* Notebook upgrade Bay BBS(CDROM, 0x0)
Boot 0002* Notebook Ethernet BBS(128, 0x0)
Boot 0003* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Boot 0004* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Boot 0005* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Boot 0006* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Boot 0007* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

I tried deleting the duplicates of:

```
Boot 0003* ubuntu HD(1, GPT,  2a721b0d-c3f1-4518-a3cd-764806d2691e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

and rebooted. It did not show:

```
Could not create variable, out of resource
```

When I inspected boot entry using **efibootmgr** I found out that with each boot up, a new duplicate is created automatically until there's no longer space for any new entry.

How do I:
- Set Ubuntu as the default boot order. I tried using efibootmgr -o . It showed:

```
Could not set BootOrder: Invalid Argument
```

- Ensure that my PC does not automatically create a new boot order.

Note: It is an old PC thay does not have any option for Secure Boot or a custom boot option.